# How do i introduce row and column span in my script?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csvtotable

I'm trying to convert table string (like csv) to html table. 
My code works fine with simple table but when it merged row and column it fails. so how do i can use rowspan and column span in the script?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<style>
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
padding:5px;
}
table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
   margin:10px;
}
</style>
<body>
    <button ng-click="processData(allText)">
        Display CSV as Data Table
    </button>
    <div id="divID">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
                <td ng-repeat="y in x">{{ y }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table>
        </table>
    </div>
```

JS

```
<script>
function myCtrl($scope, $http) {

    $scope.allText="Series |Wire Range\n (AWG) |"+
           "Wire Type |FW |Voltage\n (V) |Current \n (A) |"+
           "UG |CA |\nSL-6100 RS#2|26 16, SOL,\n Unprepared |"+
           "Cu RS#2|2 RS#2|300 RS#2|7 RS#2|B, D RS#2|"+
           "2(105), 4 RS#2|\n24 - 16, STR,\n Unprepared |"+
           "\nNominal Strip length: 9 - 10 mm CS#8|"+
           "\nEnvironmental - Maximum ambient temperature"+
           " rating for CNR: 85 C CS#8|\n";
    $scope.processData = function(allText) {
        // split content based on new line
        var allTextLines = allText.split(/\|\n|\r\n/);
        var headers = allTextLines[0].split('|');
        var lines = [];

        for ( var i = 0; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
            // split content based on comma
            var data = allTextLines[i].split('|');
            if (data.length == headers.length) {
                var temp = [];
                for ( var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                    temp.push(data[j]);
                }
                lines.push(temp);
            }
        };
        $scope.data = lines;
    };
}
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

RS#2 ---indicates rowspan of 2

cs#8 ---indicates colspan of 8

|    ---is the dilimiter for cell

|\n  ---for new line

and value in $scope.allText is CSV table string

so essentially i should get this table as output-

[image: output table]

Comment: NOTE: you are free to alter CSV string to suite spanning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an object with rows and cols so that you can use that as rowspan and colspan.

Like this

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/20561/)

```
$scope.processData = function(allText) {
    // split content based on new line
    var allTextLines = allText.split(/\|\n|\r\n/);
    var headers = allTextLines[0].split('|');
    var lines = [];
    var r,c;
    for ( var i = 0; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
        // split content based on comma
        var data = allTextLines[i].split('|');
        if (data.length == headers.length) {
            var temp = [];
            for ( var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                if(data[j].indexOf("RS") !== -1) {
                    r = data[j].split("#").reverse()[0];
                }
                else {
                    r = 0;
                }
                if(data[j].indexOf("CS") !== -1) {
                    c = data[j].split("#").reverse()[0];

                }
                else {
                    c = 0;
                }
                temp.push({"rows":r,"cols":c,"data":data[j]});
            }
            lines.push(temp);
        }
    }
    alert(JSON.stringify(lines));
    $scope.data = lines;
}
```

You can add CS to your string and alter conditions as required in this code.

Comment: TY jay... but its not able render the table as rendering is done in TABLE tag

Comment: For that you need to alter your lines logic because it requires 3 TR where in last TR, there will be only 1 TD then only it will render as per your output table image.

Comment: 1 last Question how can i remove RS CS tags as its showing up in table data?

Comment: You can override value of data[j] inside if condition like data[j] = data[j].split("RS")[0]; It will make that value i.e. before RS.

Answer (score 1):

**Controller**

```
function myCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.allText = "Series |Wire Range\n (AWG) |Wire Type |FW |Voltage\n (V) |Current \n (A) |UG |CA |\nSL-6100 RS#2|26 16, SOL,\n Unprepared |Cu RS#2|2 RS#2|300 RS#2|7 RS#2|B, D RS#2|2(105), 4 RS#2|\n24 - 16, STR,\n Unprepared |\nNominal Strip length: 9 - 10 mm CS#8|\nEnvironmental - Maximum ambient temperature rating for CNR: 85 C CS#8";
    $scope.processData = function (allText) {
        var table = [];
        allText.split(/\|\n|\r\n/).forEach(function (line) {
            var tr = [];
            line.split('|').forEach(function (cell) {
                tr.push({
                    text: cell.replace(/RS#.*$/, '').replace(/CS#.*$/, ''),
                    rowspan: (cell + 'RS#1').replace(/^[\S\s]*?RS#(\d*).*$/, '$1'),
                    colspan: (cell + 'CS#1').replace(/^[\S\s]*?CS#(\d*).*$/, '$1'),
                })
            })
            table.push(tr)
        });
        $scope.table = table;
    };
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="tr in table">
        <td ng-repeat="td in tr" ng-attr-colspan="{{td.colspan}}"  ng-attr-rowspan="{{td.rowspan}}">{{ td.text }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

**Code Snippet**

```js
function myCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $scope.allText = "Series |Wire Range\n (AWG) |Wire Type |FW |Voltage\n (V) |Current \n (A) |UG |CA |\nSL-6100 RS#2|26 16, SOL,\n Unprepared |Cu RS#2|2 RS#2|300 RS#2|7 RS#2|B, D RS#2|2(105), 4 RS#2|\n24 - 16, STR,\n Unprepared |\nNominal Strip length: 9 - 10 mm CS#8|\nEnvironmental - Maximum ambient temperature rating for CNR: 85 C CS#8";
  $scope.processData = function (allText) {
    var table = [];
    allText.split(/\|\n|\r\n/).forEach(function (line) {
      var tr = [];
      line.split('|').forEach(function (cell) {
        tr.push({
          text: cell.replace(/RS#.*$/, '').replace(/CS#.*$/, ''),
          rowspan: (cell + 'RS#1').replace(/^[\S\s]*?RS#(\d*).*$/, '$1'),
          colspan: (cell + 'CS#1').replace(/^[\S\s]*?CS#(\d*).*$/, '$1'),
        })
      })
      table.push(tr)
    });
    $scope.table = table;
  };
}

angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('ctrlr', myCtrl)
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ctrlr">
    <button ng-click="processData(allText)">
      Display CSV as Data Table
    </button>
    <div id="divID">
      <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="tr in table">
          <td ng-repeat="td in tr" ng-attr-colspan="{{td.colspan}}"  ng-attr-rowspan="{{td.rowspan}}">{{ td.text }}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div>
      <table></table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```